# LVM GUI on CentOS 7

Tags: lvm, centos7

How do you install the LVM GUI on CentOS7?

I've tried:

```
yum install system-config-lvm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
 * extras: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
 * updates: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
No package system-config-lvm available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

and Applications > System Tools > Application Installer which says lvm cannot be found.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [The system-config-lvm tool has been deprecated. Management of logical volumes can be performed via the gnome-disk-util or the lvm tools.](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Migration_Planning_Guide/chap-Migration_Guide-Package_Changes.html#idp10871416)